# How to forward ports for azure virtual network gateway?

Tags: vpn, virtual-machines, azure, remote-desktop, virtual-network

I have created Point to site vpn using azure virtual network. Right now I have

- 2 vms in vnet (with subnet ip's 10.x.x.x)
- 1 local machine connected to vnet with point to site vpn (ip 172.x.x.x)

I can rdp vm's from local machine using 10.x.x.x and local machine from vms using 172.x.x.x

My question is - Is it possible to rdp my local machine or vm's outside the network using virtual network gateway ip (using its public ip which is 13.x.x.x)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to rdp my local machine or vm's outside the network
>   using virtual network gateway ip (using its public ip which is
>   13.x.x.x)?

No, it is not possible. Azure Gateway public IP only works on VPN connection. Please refer to this [FAQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-vpn-faq#virtual-network-gateways).

> Can I deploy Virtual Machines or role instances to my gateway subnet?
>
> No.

If my understanding is right, maybe you want to your other local machines(not in .x.x.x)) connect to Azure Virtual Network and your local machines(in .x.x.x)). You could create a new point-to-site VPN from these local machines, in this scenario, you could access Azure VMs but you could not access your local machine(in 172.x.x.x)). Because Azure isolates the two network.

If you only want to connect Azure VMs in other locations, maybe you could associate a Public IP to your Azure VM and open port 3389 on Azure NSG.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually My requirement is I want to access my local machine remotely. I thought there will be a way to rdp my local machine using virtual network gateway something like port forwarding(whenever virtual network gateway ip (13.x.x.x) receives rdp request it forwards it to my local machine(which is connected to vpn with ip 172.x.x.x). I know I can directly use my public isp ip address to rdp my local machine or rdp vm’s by assigning them public ip’s but I’m just curious whether I can rdp my local machine using gateway ip from a machine which is not connected to my vpn.

Comment: @mahindar Azure does not support this scenario. You could refer to FAQ. Azure VPN Gateway IP only use for VPN connection.

Comment: @mahindar According to your description in the comment. Create a new point-to-site VPN also could not work. The network is isolated. But maybe you could RDP to Azure VM and use the VM as a jumpbox, then you could access your local machine remotely.